# Issue with Proguard

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, proguard

I am in big trouble because when I am uncommenting the below line from the properties.txt file from prject.

## To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this (available properties: sdk.dir, user.home):

**#proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt**

My adt version is 22 and current API level is 17

It is showing error [image]

This file is present in the particular folder.

Comment: What is the SDK Version you are using ?

Comment: @hungr  version is 22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have `tools/proguard` directory in your android-sdk installation (the full path is given in your message).

This proguard directory must have subdirectory `bin`, containing `proguard.bat` (it isn't there, therefore you get the message), and also subdirectorty `lib` with `proguard.jar`.

To make it work for sure, download [latest version of proguard](http://sourceforge.net/projects/proguard/files/) and place the unzipped file in the correct location.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sdk tool rev. 23, you may be suffered from the packaging bug introduced which cause entire Proguard files missing.

FYI:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72419